# What part of Quran should we teach first to Christians?

Tags: christianity, reading-quran

I have a Christian friend who is very close to Islam, and I want him to accept Islam. Are there any chapters/verses or paras of Qur'an which should be taught to him first?

Comment: Does it have to be the Quran? I always suggest when inviting people to Islam to talk about the big picture, believing in Allah and all his messengers. Then once that is solid you start with the other pillars of Islam, at which once those are solid you start into the morals, characters and look, etc..

Comment: @Zain Farooq ,here is a link which has scientific proofs from Quran which would help you a lot In Sha Allah in  convincing him as nowadays people are more interested in logics and Quran has many scientific logics for those who want to believe.http://www.islamreligion.com/category/122/scientific-miracles-of-holy-quran/

Answer (score 1):

Tell him there is nothing in the Quran or Islam that would stop him from being a good Christian. Then point to the first commandment in the Bible and to the prediction of the Holy Ghost because this was predicting the Prophet Muhammud PBUH. This is my opinion as a convert.

Then point to the beautiful short surahs including the "Time" surah 103, "The Sincerity" surah 112, and "The Disbelievers" surah 109. There are fundamental points concerning religion and life in these. For example, I think "Time" could be considered the answer to the "meaning of life" and summed up in just a few statements.

Comment: No one like Jason can expalin it as well as he did. Especially the ten commandments of Christianity and Islam, the True Spirit in chapters 15 and more of bible. And as you are convert yourself, you know very well about what matters most about Quran in terms of "effect" which we are void of(Because we are born Muslims.). Especially the "Time"! What an effect that has over my poetic mind!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you read to him Surah Hajj (23) verses 5 to 8 and Surah Ar-Rum verse 30 to 40.  Also mention that the Prophet SAW was illiterate and just a normal human being and talk about how he was born and raised.  Try to explain that Christianity all began in the Middle East and that Hebrew and Arabic are sister languages of each other.  Prophet Isa (AS) is referred to the Jews as Iso.  Western Christianity started from Eastern Christianity.  You can also explain to him that there is no direct link between the writers of the gospels of the Old and New Testament because they were written in different time periods and the writers themselves are mysterious because we do not know any other biographical information about them.  Prophet SAW and his companions were there at the exact same time period and have given narrations in Sahih Al-Bukhari and Sahih-Muslim, which are the foundations of the Sunnah (Prophet SAW's traditions and ways).  I do not know if you have a Summarized Sahih-Bukhari and Sahih-Muslim, but that would help out too.  Asalamaleikum

Answer (score 0):

Assalmaualaikum,

The first and the foremost thing we need to understand is that Allah is the one who knows the hearts. He is the one to give hidayah. We as Muslims are commanded to be polite, just and helpful to our neighbors and society in general. We hear this ayah every Friday. May Allah make us among those who practice this ayah.
[image]

If they are getting close to islam they would not have gotten closer without reading the quran. Omar Radhiyallahu anhu heard Surat Taha and accepted Islam and different sahaba heard different verses. Allah knows the hearts of his slaves and if he wants to give hidayah to a person he will give in a way we never imagined. Also, when we say recite such and such ayah they may ask us for its meaning and explanation, you may be a scholar but majority here are not. We can read a translation to them but cannot explain the real essence and background of it. Also the beginning starts from a masjid, even if you do not have an imam or a religious authority locally, just take him to a masjid and let him feel the peace of it.

I advise myself and others to be better Muslims and reflect the true spirit of Islam, that may or may not be the cause of hidayah but atleast we will not be among those who drive people away from this beautiful religion.

And Allah knows best.